# Run serially svg items

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have the SVG Ellment, and I want them to start one by one from the first to the last. How can this be realized? Here's the code:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 1080;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{clip-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st1{font-family:'MyriadPro-Regular';}
 .st2{font-size:13px;}
</style>
<rect x="899.5" y="523.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="940.5" y="526.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="905.5" y="526.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="969.5" y="526.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="934.5" y="491.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="934.5" y="561.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="905.5" y="491.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="969.5" y="491.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="905.5" y="561.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="969.5" y="561.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="870.5" y="456.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="905.5" y="806.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="1004.5" y="456.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="1004.5" y="596.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="937.5" y="456.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="1004.5" y="526.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="937.5" y="596.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="870.5" y="526.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
<rect x="969.5" y="456.5" class="st0" width="35" height="35"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: What do you want to start? "Start" implies that something happens afterward. What would that be?

Comment: what do you mean by serially? can you please tell me what is your expected output?

Comment: The result is that when you click on the button, svg appear in turn